# struct Non_const, non_volatile static or external variable

Tags: static, struct, external, non-volatile

My code compiles and runs but I still get a lint error message:

> --- Module:   LunchMenu_main.c (C)
>   } lunch[LUNCHES] =
>   LunchMenu_main.c: warning 956: (Note -- Non const, non volatile static or external variable 'lunch')

Although the use of non-constant static and external variables is demonstrated, using them has many pitfalls and they should be avoided unless there is no other reasonable solution. Is there any way I could avoid these kinds of variables or do I need these variables to fix this error? Here is my code:

```
struct Food
{
    char *name;
    int weight, calories;
} lunch[LUNCHES] = 
    {{(char *)"apple", 4, 100}, {(char *)"salad", 2, 80}};

int main(void)
{
    int counter;    
    struct Food *foodPtr = &lunch[0];

    printf("%-10s %-10s %-10s\n", "name", "weight", "calories");       

    for (counter = 0; counter < 2; counter++)
    {      
       foodPtr = &lunch[counter];            
       printf("%-10s %-10d %-10d\n",
           foodPtr->name, foodPtr->weight, foodPtr->calories);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning is probably given since your variable `lunch` is defined using a type defined in the same C file, so you cannot define other variables in other compilation units using the same type, so giving your variable global visibility does not make sense. It should be `static`.

> ... using them has many pitfalls and they should be avoided unless there is no other reasonable solution.

I beg to differ. Yes, they have some pitfalls, but I do not see any reason to avoid them at all cost. Used in a responsible way, they can help structure your code better.